# How to calculate the domain of a scalar field f(r)

Tags: vector-analysis, scalar-fields

Given a scalar field   $f({\bf r})= \dfrac{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2-z^2}}{(x^2+z^2)}$    calculate it's domain.

I have no idea where to start. I have tried to calculate $\nabla f$.

I believe the domain refers to the numerator. Thus $x^2+y^2+z^2 $ has to be less than or equal to $4$.

Is this then a ball of radius 2?

Comment: Do you know what domain means in this context and do you see why it can't be all of $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Is the assumption that $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$?...in which case, the range is $\mathbb{R}$--because you said it was... _however_ the _[co-domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain)_ may be restricted given that domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Jared the OP does mention a scalar field.

Comment: @PierreCarre I'm sorry, is a complex number not a scalar??? And there are further considerations...

Comment: @Jared You are correct, but the notation does not leave room for much imagination.

Comment: @PierreCarre I think the notation leaves quite a bit of room for "imagination" (I think what you actually mean is interpretation).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and comment on my question guys!

Comment: I think the domain just refers to the numerator as there would be no conditions on the denomintor as it could never be 0 @Christoph

Comment: I have added further information that I have realised @Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient has nothing to do with this... You just need to see what are the points for which the expression is well defined:

$$
D = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: 4-x^2-y^2-z^2 \ge 0 \wedge x^2+z^2 \ne 0\}
$$

Comment: but x^2+z^ 2 will never be 0 since it is square so does it need to be included in the set of the domain?

Comment: @butterchi what if $x=z=0$ ?

Comment: oh my bad sorry I dont know why I didnt think of that lol

Comment: Then the domain is NOT a ball of radius 2?

Comment: It is a ball of radius 2, minus a cylinder (just the shell).

Comment: thank u for your help. I have one more question with trying to help visualise it ... does that mean it is continuous everywhere except at the origin?

Comment: @PierreCarre Shouldn't it be the ball minus the $y$-axis? (a rather degenerate cylinder)

Comment: @butterchi It will be continuous everywhere in its domain.

Comment: @Christoph You are right, my bad!

Comment: @Christoph but if the domain doesn't contain the y-axis how can it be continuous at the origin?

Comment: also if the x=0 and z=0  isnt in the domain then the can we calculate the gradient at the origin? @PierreCarre

Comment: @butterchi you can only compute the gradient for points in the domain. Of course, if you extend the domain by setting some arbitrary values for $f$ when $y=0$, you can try to compute the gradient using the definition of partial derivatives.

Comment: Okay so the statement "Its gradient is defined everywhere except at the origin" would be correct? @PierreCarre

Comment: @butterchi The domain $D$ of $f$ is the closed ball of radius $2$ centered at the origin minus the $y$-axis (points with $x=z=0$). Hence, $D$ does not contain the origin. Continuity and existence of the gradient can only be asked for points in the domain. (I think Pierre got confused again, $(1,0,0)$ is a point of $D$ since it is distance $1$ from the origin and $x\neq 0$.)

Comment: @christoph I meant $(0,1,0)$... I deleted the comment.